# Concurrency in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I'm using TPCH database with sql server 2014, was wondering if there is any concurrency method for reading the data once and return multiple query results?

For example we have some queries here

```
Select SUM(Quantity) 
From LINEITEM 

Select SHIPDATE, RECEIPTDATE 
from LINEITEM 
Where COMMITDATE is Between 'somedate' and 'somedate'

Select QUANTITY * EXTENDEDPRICE * (1 - DISCOUNT) + TAX 
From LINEITEM 
Where ORDERKEY = sth
```

They all are using the same table, is there any way SQL Server read the LINEITEM table only once and provide all the results for the above queries?

Furthermore, how about having multiple tables (Like joins or nested queries) with some overlap over on FROM clauses for reading tables?

Comment: What are you expecting the results to look like?  Your second query could return multiple records - how are you expecting these results in one single query?

Comment: Let's say it's some static ID

Comment: You didn't get the question , I don't want one result for multiple queries, I want to SCAN the table once for multiple queries.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do - you could query the table with all of your conditions and dump that into a temp table, then query that temp table three times.  But I really don't see the point in doing that...  are your three queries taking a very long time to return causing deadlocks or something?

Comment: Let's say we have a 100TB database, All those queries need the same table. Now would you prefer to read a huge table 3 times or it's better to be able to read the table once and provide all the data we need for multiple queries with the same table in FROM ?

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors - even with very large databases, it may be quicker to query the table three times.  It just depends on how you have it indexed and how you have it partitioned.  Surely, there are cases where querying everything you might need upfront and querying that resultset is better.  If you want to do it that way, just `OR` all of your individual `WHERE` clauses and dump that result into a temp table and query those results.  I was just trying to see why you might need to do it that way.  Because this is sounding a lot like premature optimization that can be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot scan the table only once and get multiple results from multiple queries.